# Adding li_class on a input - Active admin

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Good morning folks.

I wonder how can i display this line of code on a controller file.

```
     <li class="string_readonly input required stringish"><%= f.label 'Contact:', class: 'label' %>
```

I have a little problem how to integrate the li class part in the controller. I suppose it would do with :input_html => {:style => " "} and so on.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see that in a controller file at all since it's clearly view code.  Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do please?

Comment: I had a top input (the contact one) in a form |do| which had a left funny way of displaying(to the right side). but i fixed. I added an if statement for editing the input and it's now working.

Comment: Fine, i'm going to vote to delete this question then since it contains no useful information for anyone.